# Какие кавычки ставить в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Какие кавычки нужно ставить в русском тексте, если в них берутся английские символы? Такие « » или такие “ ”?

Нужно ли ставить их в этом предложении: *Для подтверждения нажмите «Y» [“Y”]*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском письме наиболее употребительны следующие типы кавычек:

- французские «елочки» (употребляются в печатных текстах);
- немецкие „лапки“ (употребляются, как правило, в рукописных текстах);
- ‘марровские кавычки’ (употребляются для описания значения слова и при переводе значения иноязычного слова, например: слово «шумовка» заимствовано из польского языка, в котором оно восходит к глаголу szumowac ‘снимать пену’ от szum ‘пена’);
- "компьютерные кавычки" ­— кавычки особого типа, в которых рисунок открывающих и закрывающих кавычек совершенно не различается. Такие кавычки встречаются в текстах, набранных с помощью компьютерной клавиатуры.

Но есть еще два типа кавычек, которые редко применяются в русском языке:

- английские “двойные кавычки”;
- английские ‘одиночные кавычки’.

Подробнее: http://legart.livejournal.com/512486.html.

Корректно: *Для подтверждения нажмите «Y»*.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!